# Read tracking info without fitness device

Tags: gps, emulation, garmin

Is it possible to read data like steps,calories,etc from fitness devices like Garmin without having a physical device?

**EDIT**: virtual device or an emulator.

Thanks,
Adithya

Comment: Your question is unclear - are you trying to read adta from a device without that device? Where do you want to read it from?

Comment: Right. Like an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

The menu option `Simulation->FIT Data->Simulate Data` will give bogus data that you can test with. The simulated data isn't that great, but it should work for your purposes.

If you are making a data field, you may also have to start an activity via the `Data Fields->Timer->Start Activity` menu option. That will fill in some of the fields in the info parameter to compute().

If neither of those work, there is always the option to simply play back a FIT file which should contain all the data you want. You can do this via the `Simulation->FIT Data->Playback File...` menu option.